# Parsing JSON in Swift 3 like Apple's example for Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I am working on parsing the JSON response from the Instagram API. The top-level object includes some metadata, and the entries I'm interested in are contained in an array object called "data".

Apple's post [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37), uses Swift 2, and was published the day before Swift 3 was released (I believe). This post is very helpful, and has the same pattern that I am trying to use to get at the items I'm interested in as a dictionary. The JSON is structured very similarly.

Here is the code:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: mediaURL(), completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data,
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
        for case let items in json["data"] {
            // parse each item
        }
    }
```

The compiler throws the error "Type '[String: Any]?' has no subscript members", on the line `for case let items in json["data"] {`. The variable `json` in the `if let` chain is given the type `[String: Any]?`. How can I avoid this, and structure the binding so that I get a dictionary typed `[String: Any]` in the `json` variable?

Please note, I am not asking about how to parse JSON. I understand that. Apple's post is the exact pattern I would like to use, I would like to understand how to update the code in this post to Swift 3.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to input from the comments below, I took a closer look at the types I was using. Because my JSON had a lot of arrays of dictionaries of arrays of dictionaries, I used this code to parse it:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
let items = json["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    for item in items {
        if let mediaType = item["type"] as? String,
            let mediaID = item["id"] as? String,
            let images = item["images"] as? [String: Any],
            let standardImg = images["standard_resolution"] as? [String: Any],
            let standardImgURL = standardImg["url"] as? String {
            // Create instances with JSON data…
```

I could use a framework, but this helped me learn a bit more about parsing returned JSON that is heavily nested, not just simple flat values.

Comment: You have to tell the compiler what the expected type of the value in `json["data"]` is.

Comment: You are getting optional because of `try?`, So write it this way `let json = 
(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any] {` also you need to specify the type of `json["data"]`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I do not understand why the compiler could infer the type for Swift 2 (Apple's example does not include the type of `json["data"]` in that post, and the type is inferred correctly. Maybe my JSON is not as close as I thought.

Comment: @aaronfalls I don't think the type inference has anything to do with JSON. Remeber: Swift is statically typed! a) Type inference happens at compile time; no JSON is present then. b) JSON has only strings, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more helpful error messages by making the desired type of `json` explicit instead of wading through whatever type inference comes up with:

```
let json: [String: Any] = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...) as? [String: Any] {
    for case let items in json["data"] {
        // parse each item
    }
}
```

Now the error (at `try?`) is:

> Error: value of optional type `'[String : Any]??'` not unwrapped; 
>            did you mean to use `'try!'` or chain with `'?'`?

This gives you pretty clear instructions on how to proceed. Basically, you were not unpacking the optional but adding another layer around it! Using either `try!` + `as?`, `try?` + `as!`, or `try` + `as` (the latter requiring you to deal with an error being thrown if the cast fails) gets you what you want.

Note that you won't be able to iterate over `json["data"]` as `Any`¹ is not iterable. You'll have to make it so that the accessed data have a useful type, for instance like so:

```
switch json["data"] {
    case let items as Array<String>: 
        for item in items {
            // parse
        }
    default: throw "can't parse these data"
}
```

I'd recomment you use something other than `Any` there; maybe create a protocol `JsonData` just for this purpose and extend it into everything you anticipate.

---

1. That superfluous `case` you have after `for` even makes it type `Any?`!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the type info is helpful. Adding the type annotation to `let json` helps. The switch example you mentioned, I am not getting results, probably the structure of the JSON. I think I need to figure out how to parse out the `data` element of the JSON (from the returned `Data` instance before converting it to objects, then I can convert each element with `jsonObject`. That's what I'm really trying to do, but converting it at the top level is flattening the array that I'm really interested in.

Comment: @aaronfalls I'm glad I could be of some help! I think it's clear that I won't be able to help you with the specific JSON you're having. You may want to check out SwiftyJSON or another library that provides a nicer wrapper around the uglier standard library.